# How to get SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER using SQFlite?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, sqflite

In a Flutter app I need to get the value of `SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER` (and other similar limits) at runtime.

The documentation of SQLite advises `sqlite3_limit()` but this function is not exposed/available. I am using SQFlite package. I don't need to set/alter the values, only to read the values. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sqlite3_limit()` to set limits, not to get it (as written [here](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html#configuring_sqlite)). [Here](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_variable_number) it's written:

> To prevent excessive memory allocations, the maximum value of a host parameter number is SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER, which defaults to 999 for SQLite versions prior to 3.32.0 (2020-05-22) or 32766 for SQLite versions after 3.32.0.

I avoid the problem by reading Android API version according to this data:

| API level | Android Version | Sqlite Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31 | 12 | 3.32.2 |
| 30 | 11 | 3.28.0 |
| 29 | 10 | 3.22.0 |
| 28 | 9 | 3.22.0 |

So I solved my problem reading Android API version with sqlite3 package:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';

class DbHelper {
  DbHelper();

  Future<int> getSqliteMaxVariableNumber() async {

    int sqliteMaxVariableNumber = 32766;

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      var deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
      var androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      int sdkVersion = androidDeviceInfo.version.sdkInt;
      if (sdkVersion < 31) {
        sqliteMaxVariableNumber = 999;
      }
    }

    return sqliteMaxVariableNumber;
  }
}
```